# Separar aplicacion web JEE en módulos y empaquetarla en WAR

Tags: java, java-ee

He estado investigando como modularizar una aplicación JEE en módulos, para poder hacer que cada funcionalidad de la aplicación sea un módulo y podamos hacerlo reutilizable más adelante; pero me encuentro con que para separar ésta por módulos, debemos empaquetarla después en un EAR, que es el que almacena los WAR y JAR de la aplicación; pero la petición y mi duda que tengo es, que si es posible separarla por módulos y que cada módulo sea un aplicativo web, empaquetado en el war y que cuando queramos desplegar, todo quede empaquetado en un solo WAR, ya que el servidor que se maneja es TomCat y por lo que entendí Tomcat no soporta los EAR.

Aclaro, la aplicación solo cuenta con Beans.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes separar tu aplicación en módulos.

Los servidores como **Tomcat** sirven para contener Servlets. Si necesitas usar EJB necesita un EJB container como **JBoss** o **Websphere**. El **WAR** es un archivo comprimido, usualmente para aplicaciones web con Tomcat. El **EAR** es un archivo comprimido para aplicaciones un poco más robustas que contengan EJB.

Comment: Si, pero al final para desplegar puedo empaquetar todos los módulos en un solo WAR? Aclaro, la aplicación solo contiene Bean's

Comment: @DanielMorales lo de que la aplicación solo tenga beans es importante, ¿podrías editar la pregunta y añadir esa información?

Comment: @ordago Listo, añadido